# Python help needed: how do I produce output from 2 txt files

Tags: python

I have 2 simple .txt files.  One file contains a person's name and pay.  The second file contains a person's name and job title.

**Data from first file...**

John Doe    $750.00

Jane Doe    $450.00

Sammy Joe   $350.00

**Data from second file...**

John Doe    (Store Manager)

Jane Doe    (Asst Store Mngr)

Sammy Joe   (Shift Manager)

I need to produce an output like:    Persons Name (Job Title) ---- Pay

Example/
John Doe (Store Manager) ---- $450.00

Comment: You should add some more info, for ex how does look like the data in file1? How are they separated`... and a fair attempt of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

filename = str(input("File Name : ")

file = open(f"{filename}.txt", "w")

filewrite = str(input("Write Content : ")

file.write(filewrite)

sorry but i dont know int print its just str

Comment: please use code tags for code

Answer (score 0):

We could use the *pd.merge* function here I think

```
import pandas as pd
file_name_pay = pd.read_fwf('file1.txt')
file_name_jobtitle = pd.read_fwf('file2.txt')
df = pd.merge(file_name_pay,file_name_jobtitle, on = ['name'], how = 'inner')
```

I would validate if the names were written the same way in both files

Comment: Why using pandas when you can simply use basic python ?

Comment: Perhaps for some people pandas is more intuitive. We don't know the context. Maybe the person needs to analyze that data later. Let's give both chances.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over both files at the same time and separate out the name, job and pay

```py
def my_zip(file_1, file_2):
    for line_1, line_2 in zip(file_1, file_2):
        *name, job = line_1.split()
        pay = line_2.split()[-1]
        yield ' '.join(name), job, pay

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as name_and_job, open('file2.txt','r') as name_and_pay:
    for name, job, pay in my_zip(name_and_job, name_and_pay):
        print(f'{name} {job} --- {pay}')
```